# Does asynchronous code cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I'm concerned if asynchronous operations are prone to memory leaks. My context is Javascript used both on the frontend as well as backend (node.js)

On the `execute` operation, a delegate `IResponder` is created. It has the reference to the main module, as well as `success` and `fault` methods.

The `exampleModule` performs the `asyncOperation` and calls the `result` or the `fault` method of the `IResponder`.

My question is: I hope exampleModule is deallocated at the end of the main routine as I see there are some circular references going on with closures etc. Please advise or confirm.

```
    execute: function() {
        var self = this;
        function IResponder() {
            this.result = function(data) {self.result(data)};
            this.fault = function(info) {self.fault(info)};
        }
        var exampleModule = new ExampleModule();
        exampleModule.asyncOperation(new IResponder());//calls back result or fault of IResponder
    },

    success: function(data) { //is exampleModule deallocated here?
    },
    fault: function(info) { // //is exampleModule deallocated here?
    }
```

Comment: It's not possible to precisely answer the questions in your code comments because it's not clear what that module does. JavaScript is a garbage-collected language, and the way a garbage collector works doesn't have that much to do with asynchronous operations.

Comment: What's the point of of "IResponder"? Why not just use an anonymous object?

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe it is not. Since we don't know what `.asyncOperation` does, we cannot know, but it is like that the operation preserves the object.

Comment: You really should use `function execute(){ new ExampleModule().asyncOperation({result: this.result.bind(this), fault: this.fault.bind(this)}); }` (or just pass `this` right away as the argument?)

Comment: @Bergi I like your object style reference but not passing `this` because of coupling reasons, I came from a design patterns background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circular references do not cause problems for good JavaScript garbage collectors.

When your objects become eligible deallocation in this case depends on when `ExampleModule` lets go of its reference to your `IResponder`.

Comment: you've got it. that's what is needed. so when exampleModule finishes what it has to do, it should set responder (reference to IResponder) to null, so IResponder would be deallocated as well as exampleModule when success or faults are called.

Comment: @user2727195 that's *usually* not necessary. Even if objects reference each other in a group, when the whole group becomes unreferenced by anything else, the collector will collect the lot.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: I don't remember having to have to set references to null manually in JS many times. You probably don't need to do that either.

Comment: @Pointy that's good to know that GC is efficient in this way that it's taking care of the unreferenced groups. Coming from languages like Java, Objective-C, this was not the case so was a little concerned.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: I'm fairly sure the Java GC can handle circular references just fine as well. Objectionable-C on the other hand tends to use reference counting instead of GC as far as I'm aware, so that's another story.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen you're right, Java could handle but Obj-c will have the problem, relieved to know about this in JavaScript